# Top 3 & Sorting not working in the query. Moreover, rows get repeated when Online users are there

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am building a chat page and in that, I have 3 Dropdownlists for getting the visitors options for listing the chatrooms based on Sports, Number of total users (Total Users) and Number of currently using people (Online users).

**Individual sports ---- 1 day ----- Online users:   Works fine**

```
 SELECT RoomId, Name, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) From ChatUserLog     WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())), 0)     TotalUsers, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) From LoggedInUser WHERE RoomID     = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline From Room Where Sports = @Sports ORDER BY      UserOnline DESC
```

**Individual sports ---- 1 day ----- Total users: Works fine**

```
SELECT RoomId, Name, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) From ChatUserLog  
WHERE RoomId = Room.RoomId AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())), 0)  
 TotalUsers, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) From LoggedInUser WHERE RoomID   = Room.RoomID), 0) UserOnline From Room Where Sports = @Sports ORDER BY   TotalUsers DESC
```

[Specific sport based display working fine - Click here for the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTp8d.png)

But when I try to display only the top 3 chatrooms ranging from highly used sports to less frequently used sports', I am getting problems -

i) The chatrooms are not sorted out
ii) Top 3 among each of the sports is not correctly getting listed
iii) When any chatroom  has online users, the whole sport's items are repeated once again.

[All sport display not working - Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RcnG.png)

**All sports ---- 1 day ----- Total users: Not working**

```
SELECT DISTINCT[Sports], ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TotalUsers) FROM (SELECT TOP 3 ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) From ChatUserLog WHERE RoomId = a.RoomId), 0) TotalUsers From [Room] a WHERE Sports = b.Sports) as Total), 0) tot, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) From LoggedInUser WHERE RoomID = b.RoomID), 0) UserOnline FROM [Room] b ORDER BY tot DESC
```

**All sports ---- 1 day ----- Online users:   Not working**

```
SELECT DISTINCT[Sports], ISNULL((SELECT SUM(usr) FROM (SELECT TOP 3 ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(ChatUserLogId) From ChatUserLog WHERE RoomId = a.RoomId AND LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())), 0) TotalUsers, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(LoggedInUserId) From LoggedInUser WHERE RoomID = a.RoomID), 0) Usr From [Room] a WHERE Sports = b.Sports) as Total), 0) tot FROM [Room] b ORDER BY tot DESC
```

Where am I doing the mistake? Thanks and have a nice day ahead.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh  MS SQL.. Sorry, I ll remove MySql then. Thanks

Comment: So far as I can see, your `TOP 3`s are being applied to subqueries, where the subqueries don't have an `ORDER BY` clause. That's effectively "select 3 arbitrary rows" since *any* three rows can be considered the "top" 3 when there are no ordering constraints.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried ORDER BY in Subqueries but it is not allowed inside a subquery. So, I couldn't use it.

Comment: It *is* allowed in subqueries, *provided* the subquery also has a `TOP` applied to it. Which the error message does say quite clearly.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, you are correct. But I need not have to use TOP inside the sub query. It's not needed for my requirement. Certain chartooms with Higher Total number might have 0 online users. So, I got to join them together and then only sort and then pick the top 3 finally. Guess, I am right.